# Error is coming on using HKEY_CURRENT _USER in a batch script when accessing from command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a batch script which will be giving current browser version.
So I am creating a batch file using command :

```
C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome" /v "Version"
```

But result is coming like :

ERROR:
`Invalid Argument/Option - 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\C
urrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome'`.

But when I am using for IE :

```
c:\Windows\System32\reg.exe query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v "Version"
```

Output is :
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
    Version    REG_SZ    8.0.7601.17514`

So what is the problem here. Can't we access information from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. Please help out guys.

Answer (score 1):

Mine works with...

```
C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome" /v "Version"
```